# How can I convert a chess PDF to a HTML file to include diagrams using tex4ht?

Tags: latex3, tex4ht, html, tex4ebook, chessboard

I'm trying to convert a chess pdf to html file before converting to mobi and keeping it with the diagrams. I'm doing this through tex4ht on TeXStudio. I have the  code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xskak}
\begin{document}
\newchessgame
\chessboard[setfen=r5k1/1b1p1ppp/p7/1p1Q4/2p1r3/PP4Pq/BBP2b1P/R4R1K w - - 0 20]
\end{document}
```

and getting the error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\@tempc ...>\def \@tempb {\@tempc }\sv:begingroup 
                                                  \toks@ {#2}\edef \@tempa {...
l.5 \chessboard
               [setfen=r5k1/1b1p1ppp/p7/1p1Q4/2p1r3/PP4Pq/BBP2b1P/R4R1K w - ...
```

Is there a way to avoid this type of error ?

Comment: What exactly does "through tex4ht on calibre" mean? How are you compiling?  And is your tex system uptodate?

Comment: there's an alternative to create this command (tex4ht) in TeXStudio. I think i missed, sorry. Going to "Options" tab, "Configure TexStudio" and then on "Tools" tab, and then using the selecting the conversion by "User" command.

Comment: I don't use texstudio, so try to find out which command line call you are using.

Comment: I think you have an older version of the TeX4ht configuration file for `xskak` on your system. I still get an error with your file, but it isn't fatal. I will investigate it more tomorrow.

Comment: thank you! i dont know how to check the used command line. i thought that the code line was the only necessary information. this lokks like a common erros when we compile a file (could happen with different purposes). my main purpose is to convert pdf symbols to a readable format on kindle.

Comment: "converting pdf" is strange.  You're starting with a tex file, and using tex4ht to convert it to html and/or mobi.  There's no pdf involved in that process.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have an older TeX distribution, because it seems that the TeX4ht configuration file for Xskak is missing on your system. You can try to put it to the directory with your file, named as `xskak.4ht`:

```
% xskak.4ht (2022-11-04-13:31), generated from tex4ht-4ht.tex
% Copyright 2022 TeX Users Group
%
% This work may be distributed and/or modified under the
% conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License, either
% version 1.3c of this license or (at your option) any
% later version. The latest version of this license is in
%   http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
% and version 1.3c or later is part of all distributions
% of LaTeX version 2005/12/01 or later.
%
% This work has the LPPL maintenance status "maintained".
%
% The Current Maintainer of this work
% is the TeX4ht Project <http://tug.org/tex4ht>.
%
% If you modify this program, changing the
% version identification would be appreciated.
\immediate\write-1{version 2022-11-04-13:31}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\def\:xskakdepth{vertical-align:-\fp_eval:n{
  \dim_to_fp:n{\dp0}/(\dim_to_fp:n{\ht0}+\dim_to_fp:n{\dp0}) * 100
}\@percentchar;}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\NewConfigure{mainline}{2}
\def\:tempa#1{%
  \setbox0=\hbox{\o:mainline:{#1}}%
  \edef\:xskakalt{\detokenize{#1}}%
  %\a:mainline\Picture*[\detokenize{#1}]{ style="\:xskakdepth"}\box0\EndPicture\b:mainline%
  \a:mainline\box0\b:mainline%
}
\HLet\mainline\:tempa

\NewConfigure{xskakget}{2}
\def\:tempa#1{%
  \edef\:xskakalt{\detokenize{#1}}%
  \setbox0=\hbox{\o:xskakget:{#1}}%
  \a:xskakget\box0\b:xskakget%
}
\HLet\xskakget\:tempa

\NewConfigure{chessboard}{2}
\def\:tempa{%
  % reset to the original version of \chessboard
  \let\:currchesboard\chessboard
  \let\chessboard\o:chessboard:%
  \o:newchessgame:%
  % set the TeX4ht version of \chessboard back
  \let\chessboard\:currchesboard
}
\HLet\newchessgame\:tempa

\Hinput{xskak}
\endinput
```

It is possible that you will still get errors caused by other files. It is best to try to update your TeX distribution to TeX Live 2023.

With TeX Live 2023, I get another error, which can be fixed using this configuration file, `config.cfg`:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\catcode`\:=11
\makeatletter
\def\chessboard:alt{\ifdefined\o:xskakget:\ifcsname Xskak.\xskak@val@gameid.\xskak@val@movenr.\xskak@val@player.nextfen\endcsname\o:xskakget:{nextfen}\fi\fi}
\makeatother
\catcode`\:=12
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

You can compile your file from the command line, using:

```
$ make4ht -c config.cfg filename.tex
```

With this change, the file should compile without errors:

[image]

Comment: thanks for the support!

Comment: i tried to run again on texstudio only adding that xskak.4ht file. it worked and i got a ".svg" file. also, i tried to do the other parts but the tex live installation is really taking to long (like almost 10 hours). then, i also tried to compile the tex file on the prompt to see if generates the same "svg" file but i got the error:
"make4ht-lib: Fatal error. Command htlatex returned exit code 1"
i also tried to edit tex files on vscode but i got a new error: "Recipe terminated with error" with latex workshop.

Comment: @Cauê does the terminal list the error before the fatal error? It should print some more information.

Comment: oh true, it prints a lot of line errors, the first one is undefined control sequence. the error is too long, i i cant print due the character limit

Comment: @Cauê and do you already use the updated TeX Live 2023? The errors showed with this sample, or with a larger file?

Comment: no, the error showed with the file i created with texstudio, tex live inst installed yet (going to take a long time to install all packages).

Comment: @Cauê then there could be some other crashes because of older files. I hope it will work with the updated TeX Live.

Comment: ok, im gonna wait the full installation. thank you so much michal.h21!